# Audio/Video seems to play in a much faster rate in Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed. After successfully update of my plugins, audio/video seems to play in a much faster rate without sound. For example in 1 second, 3 seconds of music are played.
And also in youtube in my chromium browser, i won't able to play video although buffering starts as usual.

========Edited=========

Now i have installed VLC. Here video is perfect but without audio, seems that i am having some driver problem, not sure though..

It might help:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=f51cabaf71d7ff60f4c088295eae81cc96e78da9

Comment: Are you using Intel audio? It might be a bit rate problem.

Comment: Yes. So what could be a possible solution.

Comment: Do you have an HDMI connection as well? Perhaps that has been configured as your default sound output. You will see the same symptoms as described.

Comment: Thanks Jos and noleti for your comments, but i solved it myself. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i fixed this myself. I just reloaded Alsa and then everything seems right.

Below is the command which i use.

> sudo alsa force-reload